# PHP Break after 3 words

Tags: php, break

Is it possible to have an automatic break after for example 3 words?
I have this PHP code right now. Quite new to PHP so if its a stupid question

`<h5><?php echo $page->getCollectionName(); ?></h5>`

Cheers!

Comment: yes, it is. What have you tried so far?

Comment: http://php.net/ref.strings

Comment: Im quite new to PHP so I'm searching for a solution. Havent found it yet, so help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean with a "break"? A html new-line, only output 3 words in total, etc.?

Comment: Yes @jeroen After 3 words a new line should occur in the html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to break words by a space. There are several ways to do this.

```
$name = $page->getCollectionName();
$nameSplits = explode(' ', $name);
$pos = 1;
foreach ($nameSplits as $_part) {
   echo $_part .' ';
   if ($pos == 3) {
      echo '<br />';
      $pos = 1;
   } else {
      $pos++;
   }
}
```

Or you could use strtok

```
$tok = strtok($name, " ");
$pos = 1;
while ($tok !== false) {
    echo $tok . ' ';
    if ($pos == 3) {
       echo '<br />';
        $pos = 1;
    } else {
        $pos++;
    }
    $tok = strtok(" ");
}
```

There are more ways and shorter ways of doing things, but I guess this will give you an idea what is going on.

Comment: your first example displays two words on each line, the second one looks like an infinite loop

Comment: You're right. I changed my answers. Forgot something in the second and I started with $pos=0 but decided to go for $pos=1 for making it easier to understand.

Answer (score -1):

For your particular case

```
<?php

$string = "word word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7"; //Var containing our string to be echoed
$i = 0; //string iterator, same as in for($i=0;..)
$counter = 0; //count spaces
while($string[$i]) //will run trough each cell of the string until it reaches 0, the string terminator
{
    if($string[$i]===' ') $counter++; //if space, increase space count by one
    if($counter===3) //if 3 spaces have been found, echo a break and reset the counter
    {
        echo "<br/>";
        $counter=0;
    }
    else echo $string[$i]; //otherwise just echo the character

    $i++;//go to next cell in the string
}
?>
```

Please note though that you're not supposed to ask questions like these on SO. When asking, think "will anyone be able to find this on google and will the answer help them?". Try rewording your title a bit at least, I'd suggest "Replace space with new line every n words". If you keep posting bad questions eventually your posting rights will be removed.